# My son is 17 yrs old and he's going with the football team to Australia can he come back to US?

Tags: usa, international-travel, overstaying

Can my son return to US from Australia if he was a overstayer in US?

He came here when he was 8 yrs old waivers and its expired already and he still here and I'm in here too but I'm going back to Australia this month. He just got a letter from California football they invited him to play for california in Australia and he really want to go but I need help if he can come back in to US after they play in Australia.

Comment: Is your son in the USA illegally now? What is his nationality? Are you in the USA too -- legally or illegally?

Comment: He came here when he was 8 yrs old waivers and its expired already and he still here and I'm in here too but I'm going back to Australia this month.  He just got a letter from California football they invited him to play for california in Australia and he really want to go but I need help if he can come back in to US after they play in Australia.

Comment: What does "waivers" mean there?  Are you saying that he arrived with the visa waiver program?  Nine years ago?  You probably ought to speak to an immigration lawyer.  The likelihood of your son being refused entry is very high.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/123627/is-it-possible-to-go-back-to-the-u-s-after-overstaying-as-a-child

Comment: Probability is very very very very slim. Although a minor does not accumulate illegal presence it doesn’t mean it’s not taken into account in evaluating his visa application.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to go back to the U.S.after overstaying as a child?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/123627/is-it-possible-to-go-back-to-the-u-s-after-overstaying-as-a-child)

Comment: I'm not sure it's really a duplicate. That question is "I was an illegal immigrant as a child, I left for several years and now I'm an adult and I want to come back to visit", whereas this one is "I am an illegal immigrant and a child, and I want to briefly leave the US, and then return to continue being an illegal immigrant."That feels very different, to me.

Comment: It seems like the only way he would be allowed into the US may be with an advanced parole document (I-131). It's $660 for a single-trip validity document, and your son may not be eligible. It would be talk to an immigration lawyer, and see if you can regularize your status in any way.

Comment: Yes, if he's overstaying in the US, step one is to talk to an immigration lawyer to figure out what his status is and what options he has. It's much easier to do that now than to find you're unable to return and then get help.

Comment: FYI, your son does not become an illegal overstayer until he's 18. There is still a chanсe for him to leave the US without breaking the laws.

Comment: As an aside to the original question, once he turns 18 his status as an illegal overstayer will surely be hanging over him and everything he wants to do in his life, every interaction with prospective employers, government agencies etc. What happens when California football find out they’ve invited an overstayer to play for them abroad?

Comment: @JonathanReez that is a serious misinterpretation of US immigration law.  The son is already an illegal overstayer and is subject to deportation if caught.  The only thing that happens because he's under 18 is that he doesn't get the automatic ban under one specific section of immigration law.  But not being banned is very different from being guaranteed entry.

Answer (score 4):

Chances are microscopic that he will be admitted.

He is currently in the US illegally, and that gets worse with duration, not better. So if he leaves, he would not be admitted back in, and probably would not get a visa either, for years.